# how to send access code to recipient?

Tags: docusignapi

hi i want  to send access code to recipient ? how can i send using phone authentication ? here is my code but i am not getting any thing?

```
  \"signers\":[
      {
        \"email\":\"$recipientEmail\",
        \"name\":\"$recipientName\",
        \"accessCode\": \"1234\",
        \"recipientId\":\"1\",
         \"routingOrder\":\"1\",
          \"requireIdLookup\":\"false\",
         \"idCheckConfigurationName\":\" Phone Auth $\",
         \"phoneAuthentication\": {
            \"recipMayProvideNumber\": \"false\",
            \"senderProvidedNumbers\": [\"960-331-2311\"]
          },
```

please tell how to send the access code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your account is enabled for Phone Auth, you'll also need to set "requireIdLookup": "true"